# Laravel migration: How can i change the default value of a ENUM datatype?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my migration, i have a table column called "assets.status" with datatype ENUM. The default value is set to "active" and i want to modify it by changing it to "processing".

Comment: Additional info: The client doesn't want to modify the existing migration file. They want me to create another migration file and do the modification in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to create a new migration and use the `change()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#modifying-columns

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->change();
});
```

As a tip: Whenever you need to make a database change to production databases, you should never modify existing migrations. Always create a new migration, even for small changes.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Because you cant use the Schema method to update enum types, you can use the underlying DB facade to manually update the column:

```
public function up()
{
    \DB::statement("
        ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name ENUM('option1','option2') DEFAULT option1
    ");
}

public function down()
{
    \DB::statement("
        ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name ENUM('option1','option2') DEFAULT previous_default_column
    ");
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't work with datatype ENUM. Thank you for the tip on handling migration files.

Comment: @WaduNoob I didn't realise you couldn't change Enum types! As an alternative, I've updated my answer with a solution that should work. You're not restricted to using the Schema facade in a migration. You can still use the underlying `DB` object. (see updated answer)

Comment: This does work. I've solved it earlier, it's the same method you have answered. Thumbs up dude and thanks! :D